# Windows Phone 7 vertical alignment

Tags: javascript, css, windows-phone-7

How do you position a div element absolute at bottom='0px' ?
I have created a button (div tag). But i can only position it via. top.

Example:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="position:absolute;
                    width:20px;
                    height:20px;
                    background-color:red;
                    right:0px;
                    bottom:0px">
        </div>     
    </body>
</html>​
```

This aligns perfectly vertically to the bottom right corner in a web browser.
But i cant get it to work in a the WP7 web control

Comment: Show us your HTML and CSS.  Even better, put it in a http://jsfiddle.net so we can see exactly what you're trying/doing.

Answer (score 0):

`bottom` is relative to the body so you must give the body some height.

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/VL8Gg/

Comment: I tried with 100% without success.
Then i tried to calculate the screen height trying these:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068691/get-dimensions-of-wp7-screen-using-javascript

Comment: @DevNull - it works here with your HTML here if you give the body a defined height: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/VL8Gg/

Comment: The web browser control is different from the native web browser.
It is based on Silverlight desktop version, that is also different from the native browser.  
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431797(v=vs.92).aspx